# Permission denied with gcsfuse in unprivileged Ubuntu-based Docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, google-cloud-storage, fuse, gcsfuse

I was not able to run `gcsfuse` in my Ubuntu-based Docker image with `--cap-add SYS_ADMIN --device /dev/fuse`, as seen in other posts.
It works like a charm with `--privileged` though, and with root or non-root user. But I would like to avoid this option.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg lsb-release wget

RUN lsb_release -c -s > /tmp/lsb_release
RUN GCSFUSE_REPO=$(cat /tmp/lsb_release); echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-$GCSFUSE_REPO main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
RUN wget -O - https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gcsfuse
```

My test:

```sh
docker run -it --rm \
--device /dev/fuse \
--cap-add SYS_ADMIN \ 
-v /path/in/host/to/key.json:/path/to/key.json \
-e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key.json my_image:0.1 /bin/bash
```

In the running container:

```sh
mkdir /root/gruik
gcsfuse bucket_name /root/gruik/
```

The result:

```sh
Using mount point: /root/gruik
Opening GCS connection...
Mounting file system...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: permission denied
```

Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Did you try another directory instead of `/root`? such as `/tmp` as root directory

Comment: Yes, I did, and it does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an issue in docker itself and you need to run your docker container in `--privileged` mode to achieve this functionality. Check this [related docker issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/321)

Comment: Ok, but it works for others with `--cap-add SYS_ADMIN --device /dev/fuse`, which is my question at the start.